# Export Datatables from Spotfire to CSV using IronPython Script

Tags: csv, export, ironpython, spotfire

I have a IronPython script I use to export all my data tables from a Spotfire project.

Currently it works perfectly. It loops through all datatables and exports them as ".xlsx". Now I need to export the files as ".csv" which I thought would be as simple as changing ".xlsx" to ".csv".

This script still exports the files, names them all .csv, but what is inside the file is a .xlsx, Im not sure how or why. The code is just changing the file extension name but not converting the file to csv.

Here is the code I am currently using:

I have posted the full code at the bottom, and the code I believe is relevant to my question in a separate code block at the top.

```
if(dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes):
    for d in tableList: #cycles through the table list elements defined above
        writer = Document.Data.CreateDataWriter(DataWriterTypeIdentifiers.ExcelXlsDataWriter)
        table =  Document.Data.Tables[d[0]] #d[0] is the Data Table name in the Spotfire project (defined above)
        filtered = Document.ActiveFilteringSelectionReference.GetSelection(table).AsIndexSet() #OR pass the filter
        stream = File.OpenWrite(savePath+'\\'+ d[1] +".csv") #d[1] is the Excel alias name. You could also use d.Name to export with the Data Table name
        names = []
        for col in table.Columns: 
            names.append(col.Name)
        writer.Write(stream, table, filtered, names)
        stream.Close()
```

I think it may have to do with the ExcelXlsDataWriter.
I tried with ExcelXlsxDataWriter as well. Is there a csv writer I could use for this? I believe csv and txt files have a different writer.

Any help is appreciated.

Full script shown below:

```
import System
import clr
import sys

clr.AddReference("System.Windows.Forms")
from sys import exit
from System.Windows.Forms import FolderBrowserDialog, MessageBox, MessageBoxButtons, DialogResult
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Export import DataWriterTypeIdentifiers
from System.IO import File, FileStream, FileMode

#This is a list of Data Tables and their Excel file names. You can see each referenced below as d[0] and d[1] respectively.
tableList = [
            ["TestTable1"],
            ["TestTable2"],
            ]

#imports the location of the file so that there is a default place to put the exports.
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application import DocumentMetadata
dmd = Application.DocumentMetadata #Get MetaData
path = str(dmd.LoadedFromFileName) #Get Path
savePath = '\\'.join(path.split('\\')[0:-1]) + "\\DataExports\\"

dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("The files will be save to "+savePath
                +". Do you want to change location?"
                , "Select the save location", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
if(dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes):
    # GETS THE FILE PATH FROM THE USER THROUGH A FILE DIALOG instead of using the file location
    SaveFile = FolderBrowserDialog()
    SaveFile.ShowDialog()
    savePath = SaveFile.SelectedPath

#message making sure that the user wants to exporthe files.
dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Export Files."
                                +"  Export Files","Are you sure?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
if(dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes):
    for d in tableList: #cycles through the table list elements defined above
        writer = Document.Data.CreateDataWriter(DataWriterTypeIdentifiers.ExcelXlsDataWriter)
        table =  Document.Data.Tables[d[0]] #d[0] is the Data Table name in the Spotfire project (defined above)
        filtered = Document.ActiveFilteringSelectionReference.GetSelection(table).AsIndexSet() #OR pass the filter
        stream = File.OpenWrite(savePath+'\\'+ d[1] +".csv") #d[1] is the Excel alias name. You could also use d.Name to export with the Data Table name
        names = []
        for col in table.Columns: 
            names.append(col.Name)
        writer.Write(stream, table, filtered, names)
        stream.Close()

#if the user doesn't want to export then he just gets a message
else:
    dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("ok.")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason the Spotfire Iron Python implementation does not support the csv package implemented in Python.

The workaround I found to your implementation is using `StdfDataWriter` instead of `ExcelXsDataWriter`. The STDF data format is the [Spotfire Text Data Format](http://stn.spotfire.com/stn/Extend/STDF.aspx). The DataWriter class in Spotfire supports only Excel and STDF ([see here](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/doc_remote/spotfire/7.5.0/doc/api/html/N_Spotfire_Dxp_Data_Export.htm)) and STDF comes closest to CSV.

```
from System.IO import File
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Export import DataWriterTypeIdentifiers

writer = Document.Data.CreateDataWriter(DataWriterTypeIdentifiers.StdfDataWriter)
table = Document.Data.Tables['DropDownSelectors']
filtered = Document.ActiveFilteringSelectionReference.GetSelection(table).AsIndexSet()
stream = File.OpenWrite("C:\Users\KLM68651\Documents\dropdownexport.stdf")
names =[]
for col in table.Columns:
    names.append(col.Name)
writer.Write(stream, table, filtered, names)
stream.Close()
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, That is a bummer that spotfire does not export as .csv. STDF exports quickly, but then I would have to go through some sort of batch processing to convert to csv. Which I already have to do with the xlsx.... Thanks again.

Comment: @brandog They do have this capability, you may want to check it out here:
https://community.tibco.com/wiki/how-export-tablecross-table-visualization-data-csv-file-using-tibco-spotfirer-using-ironpython