# Spotfire-IronPython: Create an empty datatable and add rows

Tags: ironpython, spotfire, tibco

My goal is to write out a custom csv file out based on visualization information.

After reading each page, I fetch the filtered rows. After doing some calculations, I would like to write columns or rows out into csv file. Could you please provide example snippet on how to achieve this? 
Here is my try so far:

```
for pg in Document.Pages
    table = pg.ActiveDataTableReference
    filteredRows = pg.ActiveFilteringSelectionReference.GetSelection(table).AsIndexSet()

    # here to do some calculations, calculatedColumns/rows
    # Here to write calculatedColumns/rows into a new data table
    writer = Document.Data.CreateDataWriter(DataWriterTypeIdentifiers.ExcelXlsDataWriter) # to look if there is CSV TypeIdentifier

    stream = File.OpenWrite("E:\\Spotfire_Export\\Page_"+str(count) +"_"+ pg.Title +".csv")

    # Use writer class to write calculated columns to new table
    stream.Close()
    stream.Dispose()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Export Datatables from Spotfire to CSV using IronPython Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38866223/export-datatables-from-spotfire-to-csv-using-ironpython-script)